# Get JSON from selected node (href value) in treeview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, treeview

I fill the treeview with an object that contains id and its value, so it looks like this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var rslt = serializer.Serialize(new {
        Id = node.Id.ToString(),
        impactLength = node.impactLenght.ToString()
        });
TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(node.Name, rslt);
```

I"m having a problem getting its object back from href links of each node:

Here are some examples of hrefs:

1.Root

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$treeViewActions','s{\"Id\":\"0\",\"impactLength\":\"1\"}')
```

2.It's Descendant

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$treeViewActions','s{\"Id\":\"0\",\"impactLength\":\"1\"}\\{\"Id\":\"2\",\"impactLength\":\"1\"}')
```

I successfully retrieve the href above and get only the object string part

```
{"Id":"0","impactLength":"1"}{"Id":"2","impactLength":"1"}{"Id":"7","impactLength":"1"}
```

but when i try to parse it with [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), i get an exception:
"**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {**"

What am i doing wrong?

thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process them all at once, you'd need to build them into the Array notation of JSON.

```
'[{"Id":"0","impactLength":"1"},{"Id":"2","impactLength":"1"},{"Id":"7","impactLength":"1"}]'
```

As it is, it isn't valid JSON markup. You should really send the data from the server as proper JSON.

---

If you can't change it on the server side, then you could try this, but no guarantees:

```
   // assuming you have the part that you extracted stored in my_str...
var my_str = '{"Id":"0","impactLength":"1"}{"Id":"2","impactLength":"1"}{"Id":"7","impactLength":"1"}'

   // ...try this
var new_str = '[' + my_str.split( '}\\{' ).join( '},{' ) + ']';
var result = jQuery.parseJSON( new_str );
```

Comment: this is not possible, since every singe object represents node's value in its level.
So the only way to retrieve, lets say the last object, is by fist cutting it from the href string?

Comment: @EddieR: I guess what I'm saying is that you simply can't parse invalid JSON using JSON methods. If the format can't be changed server side, you could try doing string manipulation to make it valid. So if you have the group of objects, and since the objects have a separator of `\\`, you could try to use swap those with a comma. I'll update.

Comment: Your answer helped me alot.
changed in split the '}\\{' to '}{' and it worked successfully.Thanks!

Comment: @EddieR: Ah yes, I was looking at the original. Glad it worked.